# Remove brackets from string array when printing as csv using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I want to write a .csv file. One of the columns is "words". Each category of words is in a row, and the cell "words" has a list of words that I read as:

```
words = []

for i in range(len(category)):

    r = requests.post(base_url+'/'+url[i])

    if r.ok:
        data = r.content.decode('utf8')
        words.append(pd.Series.tolist((pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(data), squeeze=True)).T))

url_f = [base_url + s  for s in url]


df = pd.DataFrame({'category': category, 'url': url_f, 
                   'words': words})

df.to_csv("lm_words.csv")
```

the list of words is downloaded as r.

The table looks something like this:

```
index | category | url | words
0.    | cat1.    | www.| [word1, word2, word3]
```

And I am trying to get rid of the brackets in **[** word1, word2, word3 **]**.

I have this written in R and it doesn't print the brackets in the .csv

Edit1: Format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `str.join`

**Ex:**

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'category': category, 'url': url_f, 
                   'words': words})
df["words"] = df["words"].apply(", ".join)
```

Comment: So you think `df["words"] = df["words"].str.join(', ')` ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get rid of square brackets then first you need to convert the list into string using

```
    new_string = str(list_name)
```

After that you can remove the square brackets using slicing technique in python:

```
    sliced = new_string[1:-2]
```

Comment: I added: new_string = str(words)
sliced = new_string[1:-2]
But I still got the brackets.